# Passing ssh-common-args to ansible command

Tags: ssh, ansible

I'm trying to test my ansible script from my local using cygwin.
The server I'm trying to connect is failing with ssh connection with following error

> Unable to negotiate with  port <##>: no matching host key
> type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa

But I'm able to login with following ssh option
ssh -o HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa -o PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa  user@server

I'm not sure how to pass this parameter to the ansible command in Cygwin.

I tried the following, but it's not working.

ansible-playbook -i '/cygdrive/c/Test/repository/inventory/envk' -e configure_ldap test.yaml -k -K --ssh-common-args='-o HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa -o PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa user1@server' --user user1

I'm not sure how to pass parameter to 'ssh-common-args'.
Please help.

Comment: ["it's not working" is not an accurate description of your problem](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). Please read [ask] and pay attention to the [mre] section (i.e. we know the error when you don't set the option but what happens when it is?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a file named config in your ~/.ssh directory and put this in it

```
host server
  user user
  HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh
  PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa
```

then try:
ssh server

once that works you can just connect with no special parameters needed